# Creating a save file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am programming a blackjack game in visual basic 2010 express.  In my game you start with 1000 dollars and you try to work your way up.  What I am wondering is if there is a way that I could have the game recall someone's score after closing and restarting the game.

The way I could imagine it working is after each hand, I could have a document that would erase it's contents and then replace it with the user's  current money amount.  Then, the next time the program is  opened, the game would ask "would you like to resume your previous game", if the user clicks "yes" the program takes the number from  the save file and sets the money amount equal to it.

I am wondering if anyone can tell me how to write a number on a separate document, recall the number after restarting the program, and then assign it to a variable.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. [ask] (how to ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `my.settings object`, you can read more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx

This will allow you to save your coins and retrieve it the next time you open your program.

To do this, go to your ***project's property, then settings*** and create an object that suits your purpose.

Then you can set/access the values to it using

```
My.Settings.ObjectName = value
```

For your case it will be like:

```
My.Settings.Coins = 1000
```

Then on your program startup, you can put a message box that ask the player if he wants to continue, then access your object. Like this:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Continue?","Notice", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) = Yes Then
    Label.text = My.Settings.coins
End If
```

Hope that gives you some idea! :))